# find the exact position number of an id with jquery

Tags: jquery, indexing, find, position

I use the OWL Carousel 2 and need the slide number to delete a slide with:

```
$(".owl-cover-banner").owlCarousel('remove', SLIDENUMBER).owlCarousel('update');
```

How can I get the SLIDENUMBER from the html code without considering the div's with `class="owl-item cloned"`. In this HTML structure, I need an output of 0 for `class="profilecoverimagebanner_26"` and an output of 1 for `class="profilecoverimagebanner_25"`

The id already exists as

```
$(".profilecoverimagebanner_" + id)
```

This is my HTML structure:

```
<div class="owl-stage-outer">
    <div class="owl-stage" style="transition: all 0.25s ease 0s; width: 5910px; transform: translate3d(-2955px, 0px, 0px);">
        <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 1182px;">
            <div class="profilecoverimagebanner_26">
                <img class="img-fluid-cover" src="/storage//5/cover/1567847731_5d737533869b0_thumbnail.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 1182px;">
            <div class="profilecoverimagebanner_26">
                <img class="img-fluid-cover" src="/storage//5/cover/1567847731_5d737533869b0_thumbnail.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-item" style="width: 1182px;">
            <div class="profilecoverimagebanner_26">
                <img class="img-fluid-cover" src="/storage//5/cover/1567847731_5d737533869b0_thumbnail.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-item" style="width: 1182px;">
            <div class="profilecoverimagebanner_25">
                <img class="img-fluid-cover" src="/storage//5/cover/1567847731_5d737533869b0_thumbnail.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-item cloned active center" style="width: 1182px;">
            <div class="profilecoverimagebanner_26">
                <img class="img-fluid-cover" src="/storage//5/cover/1567847731_5d737533869b0_thumbnail.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-item cloned active" style="width: 1182px;">
            <div class="profilecoverimagebanner_26">
                <img class="img-fluid-cover" src="/storage//5/cover/1567847731_5d737533869b0_thumbnail.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to decide which number of slide you want to remove from which class and then do `$(".profilecoverimagebanner_26 :eq("+number+")").remove()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter without the cloned slides, loop through these and get the index from the loop, and not the element, which will result in the original index.

```js
const id = 25;

const slides = $('.owl-item').not('.cloned');
let slideIndex;

slides.each(function(index) {
  if ($(`.profilecoverimagebanner_${id}`, this).length) {
    slideIndex = index
  }
})

console.log(slideIndex)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="owl-stage">
  <div class="owl-item cloned">
    <div class="profilecoverimagebanner_26"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item cloned">
    <div class="profilecoverimagebanner_26"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item">
    <div class="profilecoverimagebanner_26"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item">
    <div class="profilecoverimagebanner_25"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item cloned active center">
    <div class="profilecoverimagebanner_26"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item cloned active">
    <div class="profilecoverimagebanner_26"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works great with existing slides. If I add a slide via ajax, it will not be found by your code and I get "undefined"

Comment: That’s because my code is merely pointing you in the right direction. You could wrap it in a function, pass in an id and invoke the function each time you need to fetch an index regardless of if a slide was added.